# Словосочетание "в начале этого года" — вводное?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлена запятая: «В начале этого года, Олегу поставили диагноз»?

Answer (score 1):

"В начале [года]" – это обстоятельство времени (когда?), а вводные слова, как известно, членами предложения не являются.

Answer (score 0):

В начале [раздельно!] этого года Олегу поставили диагноз.

Запятая не нужна – нет причин для постановки. Вы сомневаетесь, хотите поставить запятую – но на каком основании? Приведите свои резоны – будем обсуждать. Точнее, разубеждать.)

Кстати, в вашем вопросе после слова "запятая" запятая тоже не нужна. Вы пытаетесь ставить запятые везде, где в устной речи есть намек на паузу? Это неправильно.